# Simple WordPress Membership - PHP login button - how do I redirect to a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am really new to PHP and am currently trying to add a redirect to a specific page to a login button.

The code currently looks like the below:

```
<div class="swpm-login-widget-form">
<form id="swpm-login-form" name="swpm-login-form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="swpm-login-form-inner">
        <div class="swpm-username-label">
            <label for="swpm_user_name" class="swpm-label"><?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Username') ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-username-input">
            <input type="text" class="swpm-text-field swpm-username-field" id="swpm_user_name" value="" size="25" name="swpm_user_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-password-label">
            <label for="swpm_password" class="swpm-label"><?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Password') ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-password-input">
            <input type="password" class="swpm-text-field swpm-password-field" id="swpm_password" value="" size="25" name="swpm_password" />
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-remember-me">
            <span class="swpm-remember-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="checked='checked'"></span>
            <span class="swpm-rember-label"> <?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Remember Me') ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-login-submit">
            <input type="submit" class="swpm-login-form-submit" name="swpm-login" value="<?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Login') ?>"/>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-forgot-pass-link">
            <a id="forgot_pass" class="swpm-login-form-pw-reset-link"  href="<?php echo $password_reset_url; ?>"><?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Forgot Password') ?>?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-join-us-link">
            <a id="register" class="swpm-login-form-register-link" href="<?php echo $join_url; ?>"><?php echo SwpmUtils::_('Register to submit your listing.') ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-login-action-msg">
            <span class="swpm-login-widget-action-msg"><?php echo $auth->get_message(); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Looking at some other files I think I need to add something like `<a href=".....">` somewhere, but I don't know where this is supposed to go (and I may be completely wrong).

Many thanks in advance!

Kat

Comment: submit buttons don't "redirect" anything. they submit a form to whatever url is specified in the parent `<form>` tag's `action` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, Marc!

I have this bit of code at the beginning of my file: <div class="swpm-login-widget-form">
    <form id="swpm-login-form" name="swpm-login-form" method="post" action="">

Does this mean I have to add something to the "action" bit to get taken to the correct page after the form was submitted?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, your action is set to `""`, meaning form is calling the same file it's located in. Your provided form action does not really help since it's not the source we should be looking for.

To redirect to your desired page, you need to find a part where `if ($_POST[])` is. Check if `if` statement is true (by checking if form's field name(s) match(es) `if` conditional like this `$_POST['fieldNameHere']`. You can also use `exit()` to see if that's the correct part of file.

After that, add at the end (or edit already existing one) `header("Location: yourNewPage.php");`. This will redirect user to your specified file but note that it is most likely already been defined through method or another function.